# Error: [InvalidArgumentException] Database [fooBar] not configured Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to write a migration for a new table.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('fooBar')->create('tableOfThings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

But when I run `php artisan migration`, I get the following error.

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Database [fooBar] not configured.

This is what I have in `config/database.php`. You can see that I do infact have this DB configured.

```
'connections' => [
    'foo_bar' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
        'database'  => 'fooBar',
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => true,
        'engine'    => null,
    ],
    // ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the name of the configuration (not the database) is what you are passing to the connection.

```
DB::connection('foo_bar');
```

```
     'connections' => [
THIS     'foo_bar' => [ 
             'driver'    => 'mysql',
             'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
             'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
NOT THIS     'database'  => 'fooBar',
             'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
             'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
             'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
             'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
             'prefix'    => '',
             'strict'    => true,
             'engine'    => null,
         ],
         // ...
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the `fooBar` connection, but your connections array doesn't have that connection. It's called `foo_bar` instead.

Either change your connections configuration to `fooBar` or your schema connection call to `foo_bar`.

```
'connections' => [
    'fooBar' => [ // Changed from foo_bar to fooBar.
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
]
```